# KivyMD Hot Reload

Tags: python, user-interface, kivymd

*KivyMD Hot Reload*

May anybody explain every single thing to do a (hot reload) method in KivyMD?
I have been watching a lot of videos, but nothing working for me. There's no specific error to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had trouble getting it started too at first... I figured it out by watching kivymd's youtube videos at .25 speed lol...

This works for me on my Mac

1. Create a new pycharm project, set up a virtual environment, but don't install any packages yet
2. Open the terminal within pycharm (make sure it says venv) and paste this command: (you can copy the whole thing and paste it in to run it all at once)

```
git clone https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD.git --depth 1
cd KivyMD
pip install .
```

3. Still in the terminal, back out of the kivymd folder with `cd ..`
4. Then get your current directory by running `pwd` and copy the output.
5. Next thing you need to do is run this command in the terminal after you make a few changes:

```
kivymd.create_project \
    MVC \
    /Users/macbookair/Projects \
    MyMVCProject \
    python3.10 \
    2.1.0 \
    --use_hotreload yes
```

The line that says `/Users/macbookair/Projects` needs to be replaced with the output of your `pwd` terminal command. Be sure to not delete the `\` at the end. You can also change the `MyMVCProject` to any name you want

6. It will take a second for everything to install, but then you should see your project name folder in the project files. We need one more package to do the hotreload `pip install watchdog`
7. Now to open our app in hotreload... first go into our project with `cd mymvcproject` and we need to run it in debug mode so run `DEBUG=1 python main.py`
8. App should be run now in hot reload.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

## Backstory

First it was [`kivymd.utils.hot_reload_viewer`](https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/0.104.2/api/kivymd/utils/hot_reload_viewer/index.html) that got [deprecated](https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/issues/1447#issuecomment-1374521018). Then I found out about [kaki](https://github.com/tito/kaki) *(deprecated too)* and it's fork by KivyMD itself [here](https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/kivymd/tools/hotreload/app/index.html#:%7E:text=Since%20the%20project%20is%20not%20developing%2C%20we%20decided%20to%20include%20it%20in%20the%20KivvMD%20library%20and%20hope%20that%20the%20further%20development%20of%20the%20hot%20reload%20tool%20in%20the%20KivyMD%20project%20will%20develop%20faster.). But I wasn't really satisfied, I wanted something fast and easy, so I figure I could do something more simple.

[image]

## The simple way

Create `main.py` and `main.kv` files and then just:

```
pip install asyncio
```

```py
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from os.path import getmtime
import asyncio

class MyApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        return Builder.load_file('main.kv')

app = MyApp()

async def check_for_update():
    last_modified = getmtime('main.kv')
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1) # <- do not remove this 
        if last_modified == getmtime('main.kv'): continue
        last_modified = getmtime('main.kv')
        print("[INFO] UPDATED kv file")
        app.stop()

async def main():
    global app
    while True:
        try:
            await app.async_run()
            app = MyApp()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            await asyncio.sleep(2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop() 
    asyncio.ensure_future(check_for_update()) 
    asyncio.ensure_future(main()) 
    loop.run_forever()
```

<sup>( **PS.** If you want to exit just `CTRL+C` on the console )</sup>